# Boost ASIO async reconnection

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Here is part of my code.
Maybe someone can help me.

```
#include "TCPSocketBody.h"

TCPSocketBody::TCPSocketBody() : socket_(io_service_global),
                                 resolver(io_service_global),
                                 connected(false),
                                 expectedMessage(0),
                                 waitForHeader(false),
                                 waitForMessage(false)
{
    Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: TCPSocketBody::TCPSocketBody(const std::string &adress, const std::string &port)";    
}

void TCPSocketBody::Close()
{
  Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: void TCPSocketBody::Close()";

  io_service_global.post(boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::DoClose, this));
}

void TCPSocketBody::Connect(const std::string &adress, const std::string &port)
{
    Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: void TCPSocketBody::Connect(const std::string &adress, const std::string &port)";

    tcp::resolver::query query(adress, port);
    querywsk = new tcp::resolver::query(" ", " ");

    *querywsk = query;
    iterator = resolver.resolve(*querywsk);    

     boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, iterator,
           boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect, this,
           boost::asio::placeholders::error));     

     socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));

     thread_io_service = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_global));
}

void TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: void TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error)";

  if (!error)
  {           
     bool tmpFlag = connected;

     if (!connected)
     {
         connected = true;

         Message tempMessage;
         char *buffer = new char[MessageCoder::MaxMessageConnectedSize()];
         MessageCoder::ClearChar(buffer, MessageCoder::MaxMessageConnectedSize());
         MessageCoder::CreateConnectedMessage(buffer);
         tempMessage.CopyWsk(meWsk, buffer);
         messageQueue->PushBack(tempMessage);

         Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: Sending Connected message to queue: " << buffer;

         data_to_read = new char[MessageCoder::MaxMessageSize()];
         MessageCoder::ClearChar(data_to_read, MessageCoder::MaxMessageSize());
     } else
     {
         Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: Read data";
     }

    if (!waitForHeader)
    {
     boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(data_to_read, MessageCoder::BufferSize()), boost::asio::transfer_all(),
        boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));

        waitForHeader = true;
    } else
    {
         expectedMessage = MessageCoder::HeaderToVal(data_to_read);         
         Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: Expecting message with lenn: " << expectedMessage;

         if (expectedMessage > MessageCoder::MaxMessageSize())
         {
            Traces() << "\n" << "ERR: Protocol error. Message too long.";

            expectedMessage = 0;
            Close();
         } else
         {
             boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
                boost::asio::buffer(data_to_read+MessageCoder::BufferSize(), expectedMessage), boost::asio::transfer_all(),
                boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect, this,
                  boost::asio::placeholders::error));

            waitForMessage = true;
         }
    }


    if ((waitForMessage)&&(expectedMessage > 0))
    {
         Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: Message received: " << std::string(data_to_read);

         Message tempMessage;
         MessageCoder::InsertLenMessageHeader(expectedMessage, data_to_read);
         tempMessage.CopyWsk(meWsk, data_to_read);
         messageQueue->PushBack(tempMessage);
         expectedMessage = 0;


         boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(data_to_read, MessageCoder::BufferSize()), boost::asio::transfer_all(),
            boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect, this,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));

         waitForHeader = true;
         waitForMessage = false;
    }


  } else
  {
        Traces() << "\n" << "ERR: Connection error!";
        Close();
  }
}


void TCPSocketBody::WriteMessage(char *dataToSend)
{
    io_service_global.post(boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::Write, this, dataToSend));
}

void TCPSocketBody::Write(char *dataToSend)
{
    Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: void TCPSocketBody::Write(char *dataToSend)";

    data = dataToSend;

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(data, std::strlen(data)),
        boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleWrite, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}

void TCPSocketBody::HandleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: void TCPSocketBody::HandleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error)";

  if (!error)
  {

      /*boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(data,
            std::strlen(data)),
          boost::bind(&TCPSocketBody::HandleWrite, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));*/
  }
  else
  {
        Traces() << "\n" << "ERR: Read error!";
        Close();
  }
}

void TCPSocketBody::DoClose()
{
  Traces() << "\n" << "LOG: void TCPSocketBody::DoClose()";

  socket_.close();
  connected = false;
  Message tempMessage;
  char *buffer = new char[MessageCoder::MaxMessageConnectionCloseSize()];
  MessageCoder::ClearChar(buffer, MessageCoder::MaxMessageConnectionCloseSize());
  MessageCoder::CreateCloseConnectionMessage(buffer);
  tempMessage.CopyWsk(meWsk, buffer);
  messageQueue->PushBack(tempMessage);  

}
```

As we can see when connection fails then following code is executed:

```
void TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
.
.
.
} else
{
        Traces() << "\n" << "ERR: Connection error!";
        Close();
}
```

Then external thread runs void TCPSocketBody::Connect(const std::string &adress, const std::string &port) function again (after ~5s). But it looks like (from my logs) if connection still fails void TCPSocketBody::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error) is not called.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you tell to reconnect or do you call Connect every 5 seconds ?

Comment: Hi! I am sending message to safe thread queue messageQueue->PushBack(tempMessage); 
then another thread receives message and runs
object->Connect(arg,arg) after 5 sec

Comment: So you have two threads in one process and they send each other messages. I do not really understand these five seconds. Can go a little bit more into detail about that.

Comment: Here is simple example http://pastebin.com/bjuBw5y0 Of course it is simplified example. And I made a mistake in my program I have one thread.

Comment: you do have two thread, you create a new one just to run the `io_service`. I would get rid of that extra thread, and run the io_service in your main. If the connection fails, you shut down everything and you don't have anything in the `io_service` queue. That's why your program ends

Comment: I do not understand.  boost::asio::io_service must be in main? or can be in class BodySocket as static variable?

Comment: Ok when I added   io_service_global.reset(); before      thread_io_service = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_global)); I have now 4 reconnection but program crash (segmentation fault) http://pastebin.com/qeAxpBrz  I do not understand how to reconnect and how to create few connections from one client and I can't find examples. In examples there are always one connection and in examples program ends when can't connect to server